# Managing SQL Connections in WCF Service

Tags: sql-server, wcf, web-services, sqlconnection

I am currently building a WCF Web Service which may have 5 endpoints or even more. Each of these endpoints' methods will need to access a SQL Server database (for different reasons, though), and, of course, these endpoints may be called by several clients at the same time. In this scenario, what is the best way to manage connections to the database?

1) Have each method open and close a `SQLConnection` every time it is accessed?
2) Have a static `ConnectionManager` object with a `SQLConnection` property permanently open?
3) None of the above. Which, then?

Thank you very much!

Comment: IMHO the best method is to make your service work, first, and only then to make it work better.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that.  There are some general best practices that should always be followed unless there are some really good reasons not to.  Many times figuring out those best practices takes years of experience.

Comment: Timely question; I have a similar problem to solve at the moment, and had half-written a whole lot of increasingly complex threaded code before I realised I was reimplementing connection pooling, badly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach is 1) + connection pooling which is used by default if all your connections connect to database under single account (pool is per unique connection string which contains user login). Connection pooling ensures that connections are reused for multiple operations but it is absolutely transparent to development process.